# structuring C++ program with mysql connections

Tags: c++, mysql, class

I'm trying to create a c++ program that connects to mysql and can perform operations on the database such as add remove and edit. 
For each table, I want to be able to add, remove and edit as well as run specific querys to my needs. 
So far, I have everything in a single main file as I cannot figure out how to divide up my code to have one connection, and then be able to call other classes to run querys. 
I clearly a beginner in C++ and am looking for some input into what I should have in each class

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include "mysql_connection.h"
  #include "cppconn/driver.h"
  #include "cppconn/exception.h"
  #include "cppconn/resultset.h"
  #include "cppconn/statement.h"
  using namespace std;

  int main(void)
  {
  cout << endl;

  try {
      sql::Driver *driver;
      sql::Connection *con;
      sql::Statement *stmt;
      sql::ResultSet *res;

      /* Create a connection */
      driver = get_driver_instance();
      con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
      /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
      con->setSchema("ParkSmart");
      stmt = con->createStatement();
      res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID = 9");
      while (res->next()) {
          cout << res->getString(2) << endl;
          // getInt(1) returns the first column
          // ... or column names for accessing results.
      }





 //add person(int personID, string fname, string lname)
     try
     {
         int personID = 9;
         string fname = "test";
         string lname = "man";
         string query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE personID = " + to_string(personID);
         res = stmt->executeQuery(query);
         if (res->next()){
             cout << "A person with that" << endl;
             return 0;
             //failure, already exists
         }
         else {
             string query = "INSERT INTO user (personID, fname, lname) VALUES (" + to_string(personID) + ", '" + fname + "', '" + lname + ")" ;
             res = stmt->executeQuery(query);
             return 1;
             //success, user added in to database
         }
     }
     catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
         cout << "Exception caught: no query returned" << endl;
         //this is when there is no user with that userID, continue
         //check for other more specific errors
     }
```

What I am thinking is a main that calls a person class that connects to mysql and for each table there is a class that has its own connection but I'm getting seg faults

The code that I have can connect and edit the database properly, I am just lost on the actual file structures.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using Visual Studio?  If so, what version?

Comment: Are you getting unresolved symbol errors for `get_driver_instance()`?

Comment: Not using virtual studio and not getting any errors! My main runs fine and inserts everything perfectly!